# Is there an open source solution that I can host on a web server that will allow users to anonymously upload a file to me?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, uploading, server-side-scripting

I'm looking for some kind of web application I can host on my Linux web server that will allow users to upload files of arbitrary size to me from their browser without requiring them to log in.

Ideally this application would allow me to generate a link to my website that allowed for a one-time use upload. It might contain a unique, random key that was only good for that session.  I could email them the link, they click it and are taken to a page where they can upload their file to me.

I'm mainly targeting friends and family that need to send me files that are too large for email.  I don't want to require them to install anything (dropbox), sign up and log in, etc. I'm definitely not teaching them to use FTP.

This wouldn't be a difficult project for me to roll on my own but I'd like to take something off the shelf if it is possible. Does anything like this exist that my google-foo  isn't turning up?

Answer (score 2):

If unbreakable anonyimity isn't an issue and you're using Apache, try creating a page with any [php upload script](http://www.phpfileupload.org/) and password protecting it with [htpassword](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/).

I've used this as simple trick for family members before, if logging in is an issue you could just skip that part. I'd also check [hotscripts](http://www.hotscripts.com/) for other ideas.